# Sending ID data with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to fetch my id and Edit the tables value..but i am not able to fetch id from database and actually i am trying to send it by this way....

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form_company.edit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// Validate form
if (form_company.valid() == true){
  // Send company information to database
  hide_ipad_keyboard();
  hide_lightbox();
  show_loading_message();
  var id        = $('#form_company').attr('data-id');
  var form_data = $('#form_company').serialize();
  var request   = 

 $.ajax({
    url:          'data.php?job=edit_company&id=' + id,
    cache:        false,
    data:         form_data,
    dataType:     'json',
    contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:         'get'
  });

`
```

but it is getting passed by URL ..i want to send it by "data:"..how to do it..

Comment: try this, data : {id : id}, and use post method.

Comment: Please keep in mind that ajax calls are visible to the outside world. Is it ok that the id value is public knowledge? Using 'data.php' people can clean out your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post both data in `POST` parameter like below:-

```
$.ajax({
  url:          'data.php',
  type:          'POST',
  cache:        false,
  data:         {'form_data':form_data,'job':'get_company','id': id} ,
  dataType:     'json',
  contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',

});
```

And now in php (`data.php`):-

```
<?php
  echo"<pre/>";print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Note:- based on this printed data you can do your stuff accordingly. Thanks

Comment: yes after using data:{'job':'get_company','id': id} ..it works but it's fetching only ID..but doesn't get updated..(i am using it to edit table)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `type` as `get` that's why it is passing data by url. You should use `POST` if not want to pass data in URL

```
$.ajax({
  url:          'data.php?job=get_company',
  type:          'POST',
  cache:        false,
  data:         {id: id} ,
  dataType:     'json',
  contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',

});
```

Comment: what if i send it like... {'job':'get_company','id': id} ,..will it work..

Answer (score 1):

Check my changes and hope this would be helpful to you.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form_company.edit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// Validate form
if (form_company.valid() == true){
  // Send company information to database
  hide_ipad_keyboard();
  hide_lightbox();
  show_loading_message();

  var form_data = $('#form_company').serialize();
  form_data.append('id',$('#form_company').attr('data-id'));
  form_data.append('job',"edit_company");

  var request= $.ajax({
    url:          'data.php',
    cache:        false,
    data:         form_data,
    dataType:     'json',
    contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:         'post'
  });
```

Comment: i want to send it by data..not through URL..i will call only 'data.php'..and all other in data:...field..

Answer (score 1):

Try a post request with the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url:          'data.php',
    cache:        false,
    data:         {form_data:form_data,job:'edit_company',id:id},
    dataType:     'json',
    contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:         'POST',
    success:       function(data){
    }
});
```

Comment: i am getting error..data: {form_data:form_data,job:'edit_company',id:id},..is not working..

Comment: it works ..only i change it with this..small change('')..  data:         {'form_data':form_data,job:'edit_company',id:id},..thanx for your help..